# solving "NonExistentTimeError: 2015-03-22 00:00:00" error in streamlit python

Tags: python, streamlit

i am almost new in python and i encounter with "NonExistentTimeError: 2015-03-22 00:00:00" error when i take data from yahoo finance and run it in streamlit. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st
data = yf.Ticker(BTC-USD)
df= data.history(period='1d' , start='2015-04-22' , end='2017-03-20')
df
```

how can i solve my problem.
thanks a lot